# How to use function to write this code? why is it showing my a bunch of errors?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have to write a code which will take an input as the following:

`I am happy :)` or `I am sad :(`

And then convert it into the following:

`I am happy`  or `I am sad`

Using dictionary inside a function.

I don’t understand the error that I’m getting

These are the errors:

```
>i am happy :)
ERROR!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 12, in converter
UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'output' where it is not associated with a value
>
```

I tried to return the output because every time it’s gonna get updated and finally return the value as expected, shown in the photo, but it is showing me bunch of errors, and I don’t know why it is not printing what I expected.

My code that I wrote:

```
message = input('>')
output =''
def converter():
    emojis={
        ':)':'',
        ':(':''
    }
    words=message.split()
    for word in words:
        output+=emojis.get(word,word)+''
        return output
```

Comment: Unrelated to your current problem, but your return statement should be unindented.  Otherwise, it will return the output right at the first word.

Comment: @MichaelCao I wonder how this question got 3 answers, two of which fail to mention this at all, and third adding yet another `return` "in case user didn't give any input"...

Comment: @SUTerliakov-supportsstrike, I'll give the two answers the benefit of the doubt that since the stated error is obvious. They just fixed it without testing the code. I only noticed the error because I ran the code. Not sure what's going on with the third guy though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either define the output variable inside the function or make the output variable global. The format would be

```
message = input('>')
def converter():
    output =''
    emojis={
        ':)':'',
        ':(':''
    }
    words=message.split()
    for word in words:
        output+=emojis.get(word,word)+''
    return output #Use this as well in case user didn't give any input
```

EDIT - After what @Matiiss has mentioned 
if you are using the return inside of the loop, it will just return the value just after one iteration which will give the first letter only as output. Happy Coding!!

Comment: Your idea of using a return to account for if `words` is an empty list is on the right track, but currently the function will return after the first word, so you should remove the `return output` that's **inside** the `for` loop. Also PEP8.

Comment: @Matiiss i did observe that, but that could be the requirement of the original author of the post, i don't think it is causing error for the particular query of the original author. But yes as you have it will just return after the first iteration which doesn't make much sense. But that's altogether a different problem

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty self-explanatory. `output` is defined outside the function and is not in its scope.

Just put the defition inside the fuction:

```
message = input('>')

def converter():
    output = ''
    emojis={
        ':)':'',
        ':(':''
    }
    words=message.split()
    for word in words:
        output+=emojis.get(word,word)+''
        return output
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining `output` outside the function, just move it inside.
I also don't like defining a function and just using it inside a function (or at least not with that formatting).

So I would do:

```py
message = input('>')

def converter(message):
    output = ''
    emojis = {
        ':)': '',
        ':(': ''
    }
    words = message.split()
    for word in words:
        output += emojis.get(word, word)+''
        return output
```

Then, to call:

```py
converter(message)
```

Comment: I'm curious why did you decide to define extra `output` in global scope. It's kinda surprising (and unused). And please use generally advised coding style: `output =''` causes pain in my eyes... OP is clearly a new python user, so showing good practices would help a lot.

Comment: I just forgot to delete it from the "out of the function" part. My intention was moving it inside the function.